# búsqueda de documentación de php Métodos/funciones anidadas o anónimas

Tags: php

he visto dentro de un METODO que estoy estudiando e investigando esto:

```php
$pretty      = function ($indents, $varlentitle, $v = '', $c = " ", $in = 0, $k = null) use (&$pretty){...
```

esta claro que es el uso de una funcion dentro de un método (anidando) y me parece que es recursivo por el puntero `use (&$pretty)`.

estuve un rato buscando y no encontré la documentación relacionada, por que no conozco el termino/descripción de esta funcionalidad. alguien me ayuda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La palabra reservada `use` no crea métodos o funciones anidados, solo te permite [heredar variables a la función](https://www.php.net/manual/es/functions.anonymous.php#example-191).

> Los cierres también pueden heredar variables del ámbito padre. Cualquier variable debe ser pasada al constructor de lenguaje use. Desde PHP 7.1, estas variables no deben incluir superglobals, $this, o variables con el mismo nombre que un parámetro.

No me gusta el término *"cierres"* para "españolizar" *"closures"* y, en PHP, se usa para la clase que [representa funciones anónimas](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.closure.php)

En términos simples, `use` te permite acceder a variables declaradas fuera de la función que, antiguamente se recurría a la mala práctica de "importarlas" con `global $variable;`

<strike>Lo extraño es que en tu ejemplo se trate de heredar la función misma y por referencia... no parece tener sentido.</strike>

**Edición:** Después de tratar de interpretar varias veces la línea, creo que, después de todo, sí tiene sentido usar la misma variable para ejecutar recursivamente, tal vez está generando un código (HTML, JSON, CSS, etc.) y usa la variable `$indents` para agregar espacios al inicio de cada línea.

```
$pretty = function ($indents, $varlentitle, $v = '', $c = " ", $in = 0, $k = null) use (&$pretty){
    // Se hace algo con el código
    // De ser necesario, se ejecuta de forma recursiva
    // Por medio de la variable se accede a la función anónima
    $pretty(...);
}
```

Comment: lo que sucede es que estoy haciendo la reflexión de un objeto sin implementar API reflection; y se ejecuta el mismo método anónimo de manera recursivo

Comment: es todo un tema por que quiero refactorizarlo y necesito para eso estudiarlo ....

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez-TodoPoderoso, acabo de editar para poner un ejemplo al final, después de todo, si hay recursividad.

Comment: para la construcción de una librería, que se distribuirá por composer... que me sugieres; ir por el camino viejo y usar metodos y recursividades independientes (evitar el uso de metodos anonimos) o implementarlos en conjunto con closures???

Comment: estoy refactorizando y estudiando este método: https://github.com/arcanisgk/BOH-Basic-Output-Handler/blob/7e94a41cc16f5efa31c2316930061f8ae50ccef3/src/OutputHandler.php#L506

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez-TodoPoderoso, nunca he usado `closures` en PHP, pero me parece que, en este caso, es una buena estrategia para no crear un método privado aparte y creo que depende de tus preferencias si lo sigues usando así o modificas.

Comment: me parece que hay mas apatía por los closures .... y no todo el mundo sabe sobre el tema... me parece que para algo asi de sencillo voy a meterlo en un metodo privado de mas fácil entendimiento y mantenimiento